# Git submodule.$name.url override does not work

Tags: git

I have a git repository containing some submodules. For some of these submodules, I want to use a different remote URL on my local machine. According [to the Git Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule/2.22.0#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-init--ltpathgt82308203) I can do this by overwriting the `submodule.$name.url` property in my `.git/config`.

Unfortunately this setting seems not to be used at all.

**Steps to reproduce**

`git clone http://example.com/parentrepo`

`.gitmodules` content is now:

```
[submodule "mysubmodule"]
 path = mysubmodule
 url = https://example.com/mysubmodule
```

`git config submodule.mysubmodule.url http://doesnotexist.com`

`.git/config` content is now:

```
[submodule "mysubmodule"]
    url = http://doesnotexist.com
    active = true
```

After that a `git submodule update --remote` succeeds, whereas if it would be using the overwritten value should fail, because the URL does not exists.

I am running git version 2.22.0.

So why is the overwritten url not taken into account?

Comment: maybe `git submodule` is smart enough to see that `mysubmodule` is at the right commit hash, so it doesn't need to do a `git pull`...?

Comment: How to see this without contacting the remote URL and fetch the information? If I change the URL in `.gitmodules` it also breaks.

Comment: I suspect you either ran `git clone --recursive-submodules` initially, or ran `git submodule update --init` before running `git config submodule.mysubmodule.url`. Is either of these the case?

Comment: For my minimal test scenario none of this is the case. I ran `git init .` and after that `git submodule add https://example.com/mysubmodule`. What is the intention of your question?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the behavior described by @alexei above is correct, and it is in line with the Git documentation; the [gitsubmodules guide](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitsubmodules#_the_configuration_of_submodules) mentions that `.git/modules/<name>/config` has higher precedence than `.git/config`.

In this case, `remote.origin.url` in `.git/modules/<name>/config` is preferred over `submodule.<name>.url` in `.git/config`.

However, alexei writes:

> Upon init the URL gets saved in `.git/modules/<name>/config`.

That is not exactly the case; it is upon the initial `git submodule update`, or `git submodule update --init`, or `git clone --recursive` that the URL is saved in `.git/modules/<name>/config` (if the submodule clone is successful).

Also, a simpler way to change the URL after the fact would be to run `git config` in the submodule (no need to deinit and remove the submodule repo as alexei writes):

```sh
cd path/to/submodule
git config remote.origin.url http://doesnotexist.com
# or
git -C path/to/submodule config remote.origin.url http://doesnotexist.com
```

Also, note that `git submodule sync` will update *both* `.git/config` and `.git/modules/<name>/config` using the value recorded in `.gitmodules`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `submodule.<name>.url` property only affects the `init` command and only if the module wasn't previously created (`.git/modules/<name>/` does not exist).

Upon `init` the URL gets saved in `.git/modules/<name>/config`. The `update` command uses the URL from there. Even if you `deinit` the module, set the property, and then re-`init` the module, the URL in `.git/modules/<name>/config` will stay unchanged, so `update` will still fetch from the "old" remote URL. I found that to really change the URL, you need to:

```
git submodule deinit <name>
rm -r .git/modules/<name>/
git config submodule.<name>.url
git init <name>
git sumodule update --remote
```

Regarding your comment re changing URL in `.gitmodules`: you need to run `git submodule sync` to apply the change.